# Помогите дописать программу, преобразование содержимого текстового файла

Tags: c#

Суть программы в том, что есть несколько текстовых файлов, в них храниться текст, с определенными символами, пример: #Заголовок параграфа, $Ссылка на файл, который нужно открыть и ещё нужно будет сделать вывод картинок.
Сама программа сделана на WPF, в основном используется код C#, XAML почти не использую.
На данный момент реализовал заголовки, параграфы и почти ссылки, для того чтобы можно было открывать другие файлы. Но столкнулся с такой проблемой, пока не могу понять, как сделать перезагрузку TextBlock`a. И вообще ещё не знаю, как выводить картинки в TextBlock.
Может кто-то сможет помочь дописать? Скидываю все, что у меня сейчас есть.
[Ссылка на архив](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uXqoSYznpy_Casy7YuP3aDKR031LZFsQ/view?usp=sharing) с проектом.

Comment: 1. WPF это вам не консоль и не WinForms, его основное преимущество - XAML и привязки, без этого его вообще нет смысла использовать! 2. Качать ваш проект, править и говорить что там не так за вас мало кто будет, помещайте сюда то, что надо и говорите что хотите и как пробовали. 3. `TextBlock` - это текст, а не картинка.

Comment: Если вы хотите кого-то привлечь к совместной работе над каким-либо проектом, то используйте для этого, например [Github](https://github.com/). Регистрируетесь, создаете публичный репозиторий своего проекта и даете ссылку другим. Если кто и пожелает вам помочь, то сможет это сделать форкнув ваш проект, сделать правки, а потом отправить вам через гитхаб пул-реквест, который вы сможете принять в свой репозиторий, тем самым дополнив и(или) исправив свой проект. Так нынче работают программисты. Пересылкой архивов туда-сюда никто не занимается, и никому это не интересно.

Comment: Вопрос - не формат для StackOverflow. SO - это база знаний в формате вопрос-ответ. Ваш вопрос не содержит конкретики, а следовательно и делает невозможным дать конкретный ответ на него. Как итог, на ваш вопрос невозможно ответить, и он подлежит закрытию. Я рекомендую вам удалить вопрос, и если вы можете сформулировать конкретную проблему, которую не можете решить, то задайте отдельный вопрос, внесите в него (в виде текста) необходимый для воспроизведения проблемы код, а так же максимум деталей в описании проблемы. Тогда почти наверняка вам помогут, либо ответом, либо в комментариях.

Comment: ...а еще лучше воспользуйтесь поиском. Ответы на ваши вопросы 100% существуют здесь. Начните изучение XAML, привязки данных `Binding` и шаблона MVVM. Это ОЧЕНЬ сильно вам поможет в разработке. WPF без них, это как компьютер без клавиатуры. Вроде пользоваться можно, но очень неудобно.